# Passing subjects in Rspec

Tags: parameters, rspec

I'm doing my best to wrap my head around Rspec's flow, but the simplest things seem to escape me.

I want to reuse some testing for attribute formatting validity on two different models. So, I thought I would move those Rspec tests to another method and just call the method with the subject being tested. I.e. go from:

```
  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                 foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end
```

To something like this:

```
  describe "email format checking" do
    valid_email_check(@user)
  end
```

..and in utilities.rb

```
def valid_email_check(subject)
  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        subject.email = invalid_address
        subject.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

"subect" is always nil when passed to this function. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that @user is being instantiated in the test? In any case, the advice on shared examples is good.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably Shared Example Groups, a feature in rSpec to dry up tests.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group#shared-example-group-applied-to-two-groups

It is usually used when you have a parent class with common functionality, or are using a mixin to share things between the 2 (or more) classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're referencing [Listing 6.16 in the Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-email_format_validation_tests).  I DRYed up my email-related validation tests there by using the [`shoulda-matchers` gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) and utility methods, similar to your thinking.

I don't think it's best(/possible?) to put a whole `describe` block in a utility method; just code snippets you're likely to reference in multiple methods, or long bits of code like the arrays containing email addresses.  Anyway, for your reference, here's what I ended up with:

**Gemfile**

```
# ...
gem 'shoulda-matchers', '1.4.2'
```

**spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```
describe User do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  subject { user }

  # ...      

  describe "validations" do
    # ...
    context "for email" do
      it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
      it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:email) }
      it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email).case_insensitive }

      context "when email format is invalid" do
        invalid_email_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
          it { should_not allow_value(invalid_address).for(:email) }
        end
      end

      context "when email format is valid" do
        valid_email_addresses.each do |valid_address|
          it { should allow_value(valid_address).for(:email) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/support/utilities.rb**

```
# ...
def invalid_email_addresses
  %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
end

def valid_email_addresses
  %w[user@foo.com A_USER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
end
```